# Ejecutar archivo en python

Tags: python, tkinter, terminal, ejecutar

Quisiera saber como puedo hacer para poder ejecutar un archivo python en el cual importe la libreria tkInter sin tener que abrirlo desde la terminal

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Tu pregunta no es muy clara, podrías editarla y plantear mejor el problema por favor? Aun así, intentaré adivinar. Si instalaste Python desde el instalador, probablemente puedas abrirlo con doble clic y asi no usar la terminal. Pero quizá lo que realmente deseas lograr es ejecutar un archivo py desde otro. Para lograrlo tenes que usar el [sistema de importación](https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/el-sistema-de-importacion-import/). Recuerda que un modulo solo se importa una vez, por lo que si querés ejecutar el código varias veces, tendrás que envolverlo en una función.

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español!
Creo que te refieres a cómo abrir un programa con interfaz gráfica sin que aparezca la terminal. En ese caso, debes cambiar la extensión de archivo a .pyw.
La próxima vez, asegúrate de especificar mejor tu problema.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).